# How to make particular column values as upper case?

Tags: python

If I have a dataframe like

```
a     b     c

bob   ram   sam
john  hp    hcl
```

Now how do I make a and b column values as uppercase

For single column

```
df['a'] = df['a'].str.upper()
```

For all columns

```
df = df.applymap(lambda s:s.upper() if type(s) == str else s)
```

or

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lower() if(x.dtype == 'object') else x)
```

Expected output

```
a     b  

BOB   RAM
JOHN  HP
```

How do we do it for two columns at once? Like we could do the single column one twice but looking for how to do for both columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do as follow by filter the columns:

```
df[['a', 'b']] = df[['a', 'b']].applymap(lambda s:s.upper())
```

Output:

```
      a    b    c
0   BOB  RAM  sam
1  JOHN   HP  hcl
```

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
df[['a','b']] = df[['a','b']].applymap(lambda s: s.upper() if isinstance(s, str) else s)
```

Output:

```
      a    b    c
0   BOB  RAM  sam
1  JOHN   HP  hcl
```